# Only show first digit

Tags: javascript

I am making an HTML based score board for a sports event. The number (0-9) will be showed on an iPad running this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 0;
function helloup() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
function hellodown() {
    clicks -= 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
</script>

<em onClick="hellodown()">Blue</em>
<strong id="clicks">0</strong>
<i onClick="helloup()">Score!</i>
```

This works great - expect I only want it always only to show 1 digit. Meaning when it reaches 10 it should so 0.

A friend of mine mentioned the use of modulus or remainder, but I can't figure out what is what and how it would go into the code.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `clicks = (clicks + 1) % 10;`

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple possible solutions:

### 1. Using the modulus operator

```js
var clicks = 0;
function helloup() {
    clicks = (clicks + 1) % 10;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};

function hellodown() {
    clicks = (clicks - 1) % 10;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

Note:
`hellodown` will still result in `-1,...,-9`.

### 2. Checking he value of `clicks`

```js
var clicks = 0;
function helloup() {
    clicks += 1;
    if(clicks >= 10) {
        clicks = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};

function hellodown() {
    clicks -= 1;
    if(clicks <= 0) {
        clicks = 9;
    }
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```